# Not able to open "Developer Tools" in Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am learning `electronJS`.
I have a `main.dev.js` whose content is :

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

let mainWindow = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const sourceMapSupport = require('source-map-support');
  sourceMapSupport.install();
}

if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
  process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
) {
  require('electron-debug')();
  const path = require('path');
  const p = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'node_modules');
  require('module').globalPaths.push(p);
}

const installExtensions = async () => {
  const installer = require('electron-devtools-installer');
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS;
  const extensions = ['REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS', 'REDUX_DEVTOOLS'];

  return Promise.all(
    extensions.map(name => installer.default(installer[name], forceDownload))
  ).catch(console.log);
};

/**
 * Add event listeners...
 */

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // Respect the OSX convention of having the application in memory even
  // after all windows have been closed
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
    process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
  ) {
    await installExtensions();
  }

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 728
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html`);

  // @TODO: Use 'ready-to-show' event
  // https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#using-ready-to-show-event
  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    if (!mainWindow) {
      throw new Error('"mainWindow" is not defined');
    }
    if (process.env.START_MINIMIZED) {
      mainWindow.minimize();
    } else {
      mainWindow.show();
      mainWindow.focus();
    }
  });

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Whose output is :

[image]

But nothing is happening on click `Toggle Developer Tools` option.
I am NOT able to find the issue ?

### Note :

I want to debug an electron app whose git repo is : [git repo](https://github.com/bharathvaj-ganesan/picart)
You can also clone the repo if needed ...

---

I am NOT able to post my question because of this error (please ignore) :

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>
> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>
> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Do you have any (error) output on the console? You could try opening the devtools from the Main process, by using `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` after creating the window.

Comment: I have tried everything, but nothing is working. Please use the git repo (given in question description) and try to figure out.

Comment: You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72866089/how-to-open-inspect-element-in-electron-app) asked by me.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works (see [ask]). You're responsible for debugging your own app, we cannot clone your repository, then debug the app, write an answer and provide a patch. However, we can provide you with specific solutions to specific problems. It seems your new question duplicated this one, so I'm going to leave this one alone. Btw, "I tried everything" is all but helpful – what I meant was whether you tried calling `openDevTools()` immediately after assigning `mainWindow`. In my experience, this always works and reveals some sort of error.

Comment: I have tried `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` after assigning `mainWindow`. But not working. I am not getting any error on console.

Comment: I saw in your other question that you run Kubuntu 22.04. I'm experiencing the same trouble with Ubuntu 22.04 since I upgraded from 20.04... Maybe it's related. There is maybe a bug with this version of electron.
What is your electron version?

Comment: I updated Electron to the last version and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with an electron app (electon js 22.2) : devTools stopped working after I added require('exceljs') to my code.
On electronjs repo on github, there is an [opened issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/36452) for that problem.. here is a workaround (from a comment on that issue) :

```
mainWindow.on("ready-to-show", () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the electron version to the last one like `23.1.1`.
It seems to fix the problem in my environment.